# Wildcard query with dot return results even without dot

Tags: elasticsearch

Do the following query

```
GET /ind/_search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : { "val.keyword": "*.*" }
    }
}
```

But in the result I got not only a value with a dot, but also without. I tried to write `"*/.*"` - do not shown values even with a dot.

In ES mapping for this field:

```
        "val": {
          "type": "long",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
GET /ind/_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "val.keyword": "*.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing is returned on this query